# Latex footer issue

Tags: footer, pagestyle

I have use this template and want to add a line in the footer. Can anyone please give a support?

```
\usepackage [headsepline, markcase = noupper] { scrlayer-scrpage }
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead[]{\pagemark}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
%\automark[chapter]{section}
\ihead[]{\headmark}
\ifoot[]{}
```

Comment: Add `footsepline` to the options of `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my issue. I still have another problem while using `\automark[chapter]{section}`, it  gives incorrect header. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. Please also add a description or sketch that shows the outpu you expect.